# Is it possible to have multiple keyframes in an xml-animation in Android Studio?

Tags: android, css, xml

I have a TextView that I want to change in size multiple times using an animation, similar to the way it is possible in CSS using keyframes:

```
@keyframes scaleUp {
    0% {  transform: scale(0,0); }
    50% {  transform: scale(1,1); }
    70% {  transform: scale(0,0); }
    100% { transform: scale(1,1); }
}
```

In XML however, the only way I was able to find to do animations is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

`android:fromXScale` and `android:toXScale` are equivalent to the 0% and 100% in my CSS code sample. Is there any equivalent to 50% and 70% or is it possible to otherwise achieve a similar effect? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody is still wondering how to do this, I found a solution ( I don't know if this is the perfect way to go about this, but it works). You can just add multiple animations to the file, each with a delay, that is equal to the duration of all the previous animations. This way the subsequent animations will trigger when the previous one ended.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="3000"/>
<scale
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:startOffset = "3000"/>
</set>
```